# Find all $n$ such that $7$ divides $(2n+2)2^{n-1}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For which $n$ the equation $(2n+2)\cdot 2^{n-1}\equiv 0\pmod{7}$

So I can look in this way? for which $k\in\mathbf{Z}$:
$$
(2n+2)\cdot 2^{n-1}\equiv 7\cdot k \pmod{7}\,\,?
$$

Comment: Are you sure this question was typed correctly?  $2^{n-1}$ is never divisible by $7$, clearly, so it can be ignored.  Perhaps it should have read $2^n-1$?

Comment: @lulu yes this is the expression (it was a question on when a finite field matrix is not invertible, and this was the expression I came to, and it is correct)

Comment: Ok.  In that case, the posted solution below is entirely correct.  Just ignore the power of 2, and ask when $7$ divides $2n+2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$2$ (and its powers) are invertible mod $7$. Hence the solution is 
$$
n\equiv -1 \pmod{7}.
$$

Comment: Therefore $(2n+2)\equiv 7$ (mod 7)?

Comment: Again, factorize and "delete" $2$

Comment: sorry I did not understand

Comment: Alternatively, consider that $2^{n-1}(2n+2)=2^n(n+1)$, so just cancel the $2^n$, and you get that $7$ divides $n+1$..